# Whether to use generics or not?

Tags: java, generics

I have the following hierarchy of classes

```
public abstract class MyAbstractClass {

}

public abstract class AbstractClassA extends MyAbstractClass {

}
public class AbstractClassB extends MyAbstractClass {

}
public class ClassA extends AbstractClassA {

}
public class ClassB extends AbstractClassA {

}
```

I have a converter which should accept instance of a `class` extending `AbstractClassA` and should return `instance` of a `class` extending `AbstractClassB`. I have two versions of conversion class one using Generic and the other one is not. Both works fins. But what is the correct way of specifying the signature of the converter?

```
public class ConverterTwo {
    public AbstractClassB convert(AbstractClassA a) {
}
}

public class ConverterOne {
public <A extends AbstractClassA, B extends AbstractClassB> B convert(A a) {
}
}
```

Comment: There is no "incorrect" way here

Comment: It all depends on the Converter logic, i.e. whether it depends on the Concrete classes or only AbstractA and AbstractB.

Comment: My converter works based on the fields of abstract classes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generics are checked only at compile time and are replaced with the proper types during compilation.

`ConverterTwo` code will be converted to `ConverterOne` kind of code during compilation and thus both are equivalent.

Generics are especially useful when you write an **API** where you do not know what kind of objects the consumer of the API's are going to pass. 
In your case, if you plan to write a generic adapter.

Classic example of genrics : Collection Interface and the classes that implement it.

Answer (score 0):

Use 1, you have all the type checking you need because the parameters extend an abstract class. And its less code than 2, which always a good thing. But neither would be **wrong**.

Answer (score 0):

Both are correct ways. It's just that `ConverterTwo` class has less code in signature as compared to `ConverterOne`. Also both the syntax `AbstractClassA` and `<A extends AbstractClassA>` will behave in same manner in this example.

Answer (score 0):

Both are correct but my suggestion is go with `ConverterTwo` which is simpler. You can always Generify and make a **Generic Interface** or Abstract class out of your Converter later.